# Show correlations as an ordered list, not as a large matrix

Tags: r

I've a data frame with 100+ columns. cor() returns remarkably quickly, but tells me far too much, especially as most columns are not correlated. I'd like it to just tell me column pairs and their correlation, ideally ordered.

In case that doesn't make sense here is an artificial example:

```
df = data.frame(a=1:10,b=20:11*20:11,c=runif(10),d=runif(10),e=runif(10)*1:10)
z = cor(df)
```

z looks like this:

```
           a          b           c           d          e
a  1.0000000 -0.9966867 -0.38925240 -0.35142452  0.2594220
b -0.9966867  1.0000000  0.40266637  0.35896626 -0.2859906
c -0.3892524  0.4026664  1.00000000  0.03958307  0.1781210
d -0.3514245  0.3589663  0.03958307  1.00000000 -0.3901608
e  0.2594220 -0.2859906  0.17812098 -0.39016080  1.0000000
```

What I'm looking for is a function that will instead tell me:

```
a:b -0.9966867 
b:c  0.4026664
d:e -0.39016080  
a:c -0.3892524 
b:d  0.3589663
a:d -0.3514245 
b:e -0.2859906
a:e  0.2594220 
c:e  0.17812098
c:d  0.03958307
```

I have a crude way to get rid of some of the noise:

```
z[abs(z)<0.5]=0
```

then scan looking for non-zero values. But it is far inferior to the desired output above.

UPDATE:
Based on the answers received, and some trial and error, here is the solution I went with:

```
z[lower.tri(z,diag=TRUE)]=NA  #Prepare to drop duplicates and meaningless information
z=as.data.frame(as.table(z))  #Turn into a 3-column table
z=na.omit(z)  #Get rid of the junk we flagged above
z=z[order(-abs(z$Freq)),]    #Sort by highest correlation (whether +ve or -ve)
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6782070/210673

Comment: @Aaron Yes, it is exactly the same question. My apologies! (I did skim the Related Questions list, but completely missed that one.) But it is educational (to me at least) to note the similarities and differences in the answers.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I always use

```
zdf <- as.data.frame(as.table(z))
zdf
#    Var1 Var2     Freq
# 1     a    a  1.00000
# 2     b    a -0.99669
# 3     c    a -0.14063
# 4     d    a -0.28061
# 5     e    a  0.80519
```

Then use `subset(zdf, abs(Freq) > 0.5)` to select significant values.

Comment: Thanks. It still includes the diagonal, includes each correlation twice, and isn't sorted, but I used it as the starting point for the solution I went with.

Answer (score 8):

```
library(reshape)

z[z == 1] <- NA #drop perfect
z[abs(z) < 0.5] <- NA # drop less than abs(0.5)
z <- na.omit(melt(z)) # melt! 
z[order(-abs(z$value)),] # sort
```

Comment: Brilliant! melt rarely jumps out at me to be used.

Comment: Thanks. `z[z==1] <- NA` is dangerous as it also removes genuine perfect correlations (better to use `z[lower.tri(z,diag=TRUE)]=NA`). BTW, in this case melt(z) does exactly (?) the same as as.data.frame(as.table(z)), so it can be done without other packages.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of @Marek's answer.
Eliminates diagonal and duplicates

```
data = as.data.frame( as.table( z ) )
combinations = combn( colnames( z ) , 2 , FUN = function( x ) { paste( x , collapse = "_" ) } )
data = data[ data$Var1 != data$Var2 , ]
data = data[ paste( data$Var1 , data$Var2 , sep = "_" ) %in% combinations , ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the answer by Marek, I added a few lines for common cleaning using [Tidyverse pipes](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tidyverse-tutorial-r):

```
  df_cor %>%                               # start from the correlation matrix
  as.table() %>% as.data.frame() %>%       # Marek's answer in TidyVerse format
  subset(Var1 != Var2 & abs(Freq)>0.5) %>% # omit diagonal and keep significant correlations (optional...)
  filter(!duplicated(paste0(pmax(as.character(Var1), as.character(Var2)), pmin(as.character(Var1), as.character(Var2))))) %>%
                                           # keep only unique occurrences, as.character because Var1 and Var2 are factors
  arrange(desc(Freq))                      # sort by Freq
```

More on line 4 here: [How do I select all unique combinations of two columns in an R data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752211/how-do-i-select-all-unique-combinations-of-two-columns-in-an-r-data-frame)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to visualize correlation matrices so that one can get a quick picture of the data set. Here is a [link](http://weitaiyun.blogspot.com/2009/03/visulization-of-correlation-matrix.html) to an approach which looks pretty good.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Of course, with 100+ columns it gets a bit impractical (except perhaps if my columns were clustered in some meaningful way).