# Extract one triangle of a correlation matrix with attributes

Tags: r, attributes, correlation

I have a dataframe/matrix of equal rows and columns. I want to extract only the upper or lower triangle.

```
x<-data.frame(matrix(1:25,nrow=5))
colnames(x)<-LETTERS[1:5]
rownames(x)<-LETTERS[1:5]

x[upper.tri(x,diag=F)]
```

From this result, it is not possible to say what combination of column and row the value came from. So, I would like to have the row and column attributes in the results. Something like this:

```
Col Row Val
B   A   6
C   A   11
C   B   12
...
```

I need to do this for a large correlation matrix.
Thanks.

Comment: Was one of the below solutions useful? If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to make things unambiguous, I change

```
colnames(x) <- LETTERS[6:10]
```

Use `expand.grid` to get the row and column names like this

```
rowCol <- expand.grid(rownames(x), colnames(x))
```

To get the correct rows from this data frame, take

```
labs <- rowCol[as.vector(upper.tri(x,diag=F)),]
df <- cbind(labs, x[upper.tri(x,diag=F)])
colnames(df) <- c("Row","Col","Val")
df[,c(2,1,3)]
##    Col Row Val
## 6    G   A   6
## 11   H   A  11
## ...
```

Comment: `expand.grid` is too slow. Try `data.table::CJ` instead: `rowCol <- data.table::CJ(rownames(x), colnames(x), sorted = F)`

Answer (score 6):

I'd just use `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` like this:

```
ind <- which( upper.tri(x,diag=F) , arr.ind = TRUE )

data.frame( col = dimnames(x)[[2]][ind[,2]] ,
            row = dimnames(x)[[1]][ind[,1]] ,
            val = x[ ind ] )

   col row val
1    B   A   6
2    C   A  11
3    C   B  12
4    D   A  16
5    D   B  17
6    D   C  18
7    E   A  21
8    E   B  22
9    E   C  23
10   E   D  24
```

Answer (score 1):

... this might be a solution

```
nam <-apply(ind, 2, function(y, x) rownames(x)[c(y)], x=x)   
cbind(nam, x[upper.tri(x,diag=F)])
```

hth

Comment: Thanks. I just found the solution here..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074246/show-correlations-as-an-ordered-list-not-as-a-large-matrix

Answer (score 0):

The lower triangle is defined with the expression "column index is not greater than the row index".
This code gives the lower triangle (or upper by switching the > operator) a value of 0.  Use "" in place of 0 to keep the triangle.

```
x[!(col(x) > index(x))] <- 0
```

To produce a data set as in the original post, I would use reshape2::melt and dplyr::(filter, select) functions.

First create an id variable to melt on.

```
x$id <- rownames(x)
```

Then,

```
melt(x, id = "id") %>%
 filter(value > 0 ) %>%
   select(Col = variable, Row = id, Val = value)

   Col Row Val
1    B   A   6
2    C   A  11
3    C   B  12
4    D   A  16
5    D   B  17
6    D   C  18
7    E   A  21
8    E   B  22
9    E   C  23
10   E   D  24
```