# Display Correlation and pvalues as a list and erase which doesn't meet certain features

Tags: r, correlation, feature-selection, p-value

I´m trying to display in a list which tells me column pairs, their correlation and pvalues. Then eliminate those which have a correlation < 0.5 & pvalues > 0.06.
Using the next matrix

```
r <- 33
c <- 6
m0 <- matrix(0, r, c)
matriz<-apply(m0, c(1,2), function(x) sample(c(0,1),1))
cor.m<-cor.prob(matriz)
```

Then we'll have over the diagonal the pvalues and below the correlation.
Using a similar answer I found from [Show correlations as an ordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074246/show-correlations-as-an-ordered-list-not-as-a-large-matrix/26857141#26857141) but I tried to show the pvalues also, without success. Then I tried at least to erase those datas wich have correlation< 0.5 using the following code

```
cor.m[upper.tri(cor.m,diag=TRUE)]=NA  
cor.m<-as.data.frame(as.table(cor.m)) 
cor.m<-na.omit(cor.m)  
cor.m<-cor.m[-c((cor.m$Freq<'0.5')), ]  #but this erase no matter the feature
```

then tried this loop but it generate an error "Error en if (corx1$Freq[i] < 0.2) {  waiting for TRUE/FALSE value:" and also changes the column with the pair of data

```
# then tried this with same results
for (i in 1:nrow(cor.m) ){ 
    if(cor.m$Freq[i]<0.2){
        cor.m<- as.data.frame(as.table(cor.m$Freq[-i]))
    }
}
```

Comment: I already found in other site how to fix this problem, I will left the site here [link](http://www.r-bloggers.com/more-on-exploring-correlations-in-r/)

Comment: to meet the features I used subset which is easier than doing it with an if