# Sort for top matrix correlations and remove reverse duplicates without apply

Tags: r, matrix, reshape

I have a correlation matrix and I need to extract the top values and remove the reverse duplicates (sw6 & sw4 = 0.6 correlated means the same as sw4 & sw6 = 0.6).

I used an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074246/show-correlations-as-an-ordered-list-not-as-a-large-matrix/7074856) that uses reshape to output the top correlations above 0.5. Now my only problem is that there are reverse duplicates. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756392/deleting-reversed-duplicates-with-r) question here does pretty much what I want which is to remove these reverse duplicates, but only with `apply` which I'm afraid may slow down my code for large sets. Is there a way to remove reverse dupes without it?

Or is there a better way to get the top correlations of a matrix while only producing unique combinations?

Output after the reshape melt looks like this:

`X1  X2     value
sw6 sw4   0.6299408
sw4 sw6   0.6299408
ss  sl    0.5833333
sl  ss    0.5833333
id  ty    0.5724780
ty  id    0.5724780
sl  br    0.5333965
br  sl    0.5333965`

But every two rows are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to replace either the `upper.tri` or `lower.tri` to `NA` and then `melt`.  This had the advantage of pre-processing without having to post-process.  For large datasets, it would be better to do pre-processing rather than convert to long dataset and then remove the duplicates

```
library(reshape2)
m1[lower.tri(m1, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
melt(m1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

NOTE: Also, no need for any additional packages except the one the OP is already using

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I dreamed of but didn't think was possible, removing half the matrix. Brilliant and so easy, thank you so much.