# get element of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a correlation matrix (Corr) with factor names A,B,C,D,E  (they are set as col names and rownames).

I want to create a data frame in format Factor1,Factor2,Corr so I can save it in a database.

I am using **sqldf** to get all the combinations of these factors using query below.

```
SELECT a.Factor as FactorA,
       b.Factor as FactorB 
FROM Factors a cross JOIN Factors b 
WHERE a.Factor>b.Factor
```

So that I have exactly 5C2 rows.

Now I want to use this result to lookup col name and row name in the correlation matrix to get the related correlation factor. Is there any way I can use *apply function as I want to avoid iterations.

dataframe should look like

FactorA,FactorB,Corr[FactorA,FactorB]

I would really appreciate any help..

Comment: I think I might understand but it would be much easier to tell if you provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Near duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782070 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074246.

Answer (score 2):

1) Try this where `Corr` is your correlation matrix, e.g. `Corr <- cor(iris[-5])` :

```
subset(as.data.frame.table(Corr), as.numeric(Var1) > as.numeric(Var2))
```

2) If you want to use [sqldf](http://sqldf.googlecode.com) then try this:

```
library(sqldf)
DF <- as.data.frame.table(Corr)
sqldf("select * from DF where Var1 > Var2")
```

EDIT: added solution where sqldf is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- expand.grid(colnames(Corr), rownames(Corr))
df$Corr <- apply(df, 1, function(x) Corr[ x[1], x[2] ])
Ltri <- lower.tri(Corr)
df[ Ltri , ]   # the lower triangular data

# I used the longley dataset and the second example on the `cor` help page to test
# (Corr <- cor(longley))
```

As typically happens when @G.Grothendieck answers a question, his answer is more appealing than mine. In this case it suffers a bit IMO from the fact that it needs to recover a numeric index from  factors. On the other hand, I always worry a bit when I use `upper.tri` or `lower.tri`, since they also seem very unintuitive, because they do not return the elements until you use them as indices with "[". Either one of us could have used row(Corr) > col(Corr) to the same effect and it would have appeared clearer to my way of thinking.

Alternate selection:

```
df[ row(Corr) > col(Corr) , ]
subset(as.data.frame.table(Corr), row(Corr) > col(Corr))
```