# correlation matrix with names

Tags: r

I have a matrix of about 1000 row X 500 variable, I am trying to establish a correlation matrix for these variables with names rather than numbers, so the outcome should look like this

```
variable1    variable2    variable3    variable4 ...
  mrv1         mrv2         mrv3          mrv4   ...
 smrv1        smrv2        smrv3          smrv4   ...
   .             .           .             .
   .             .           .             .
   .             .           .             .
```

where mrv1 = Most related variable to variable1, smrv1 = second most related variable and so on.

I have actually made the correlation matrix, but using a for loop and a very complicated command (probably the worst command of all time, but it actually works!). I am looking forward to establish this through a proper command, here's the command I am using now.

```
mydata <- read.csv("location", header=TRUE, sep=",")
lgn <- length(mydata)
crm <- cor(mydata)

k <- crm[,1]
K <- data.frame(rev(sort(k)))
A <- data.frame(rownames(K))

for (x in 2:lgn){
k <- crm[,x]
K <- data.frame(rev(sort(k)))
B <- data.frame(rownames(K)) 
A <- cbind(A,B)
}
```

Any ideas of a more simple, reliable command?

Thanks,

Comment: Is this helpful?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782070/display-correlation-tables-as-descending-list/6782814#6782814

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this example work for what you want?

```
W <- rnorm( 10 )
X <- rnorm( 10 )
Y <- rnorm( 10 )
Z <- rnorm( 10 )

df <- round( cor( cbind( W , X , Y , Z ) ) , 2 )
df
#         W     X     Y     Z
#   W  1.00 -0.50 -0.36 -0.27
#   X -0.50  1.00 -0.42 -0.02
#   Y -0.36 -0.42  1.00  0.17
#   Z -0.27 -0.02  0.17  1.00


apply( df , 2 , FUN = function(x){ j <- rev(order(x)); y <- names(x)[j]  } )
#        W   X   Y   Z  
#   [1,] "W" "X" "Y" "Z"
#   [2,] "Z" "Z" "Z" "Y"
#   [3,] "Y" "Y" "W" "X"
#   [4,] "X" "W" "X" "W"


#And use abs() if you don't care about the direction of the correlation (negative or postive) just the magnitude
apply( df , 2 , FUN = function(x){ j <- rev(order(   abs(x)   )); y <- names(x)[j]  } )
#        W   X   Y   Z  
#   [1,] "W" "X" "Y" "Z"
#   [2,] "X" "W" "X" "W"
#   [3,] "Y" "Y" "W" "Y"
#   [4,] "Z" "Z" "Z" "X"
```

Answer (score 1):

To visualize the relationships in a correlation matrix you might consider doing a cluster analysis.  Use one minus the correlation matrix as the distance matrix (or possibly one minus the absolute value of the correlation matrix) then pass that to a function like `agnes` or other cluster function.  The ordering and plots with that may be informative.