# keep var format as matrix after removing values

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to print out the values of a correlation matrix as an ordered list using the code below adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782070/display-correlation-tables-as-descending-list). Can someone explain how to get output from only the lower half of the correlation matrix, and have it display row and column names instead of `colN`?

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
    col1 = rnorm(10),
    col2 = rnorm(10),
    col3=rnorm(10)
)
row.names(df)<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J")

cors<-cor(df)
library(reshape)
x <- subset(melt(cors), value != 1 | value != NA)
x <- x[with(x, order(-abs(x$value))),]
#x$value<-signif(x$value,2)
head(x)
```

Example of what I was hoping for:

```
row names col names  corr vales
col3      col2        0.60
col2      col1       -0.38
col3      col1       -0.72
```

Comment: Could you make your example reproducible?

Comment: I am not very familiar with R yet. Is there any chance you could suggest a dataset from an existing package with variable names? I am unsure how to find one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lower.tri` to index your data.

```
cors <- cor(df)
as.data.frame.table(cors)[lower.tri(cors),]

#  Var1 Var2       Freq
#2 col2 col1 -0.3767034
#3 col3 col1 -0.7158385
#6 col3 col2  0.6040273
```

If you must have the names changed, then just wrap it all in `setNames()`:

```
setNames(as.data.frame.table(cors)[lower.tri(cors),], c("row","col","corr"))
```